# woocommerce wc_get_orders return empty

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a simply code to get all commands

```
    public function myfunction()
{
    $file = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/myplugin/logs.txt';
    global $wpdb;
    $args = array(
        'limit' => -1,
        'status' => array('to-print') // personal status
    );
    $orders = wc_get_orders($args);
    file_put_contents($file, 'orders : ' . json_encode($orders) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
}
```

I don't know that return me an empty array. Don't work without status.

Comment: this should help you get on the right path: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query

Comment: please post the code showing how you registered the `to-print` order status

Comment: I've already seen this post but despite everything after several tries following the examples, I can't get anything (even without the status 'to-print', it doesn't work)

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work. If it returns an empty array and you DO have orders, it's most probably an arg ( like the status ) that filters out orders. Make sure you have at least one order in status `wc-completed` and then run the code without the `status` argument and check the contents of the `$orders` variable.

Comment: Even with status wc-completed, it doesn't work.
I would check with the person who did the rest of the plugin code to see if he did something that could block it.
THANKS.
I'll keep you informed

Comment: Could the problem come from the fact that the function is called via a cron method ?
And / or a call to the different functions available by Woocommerce ?

Comment: I think I found the problem.
The problem does not come from Woocommerce but the logs.
I use:
"file_put_contents($file, 'orders: ' . json_encode($orders) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
To log my results and I don't know why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.